# How to remove space between date separators in biblatex (style footnote-dw)

Tags: spacing, biblatex-dw

If I use biblatex's style `footnote-dw` and the option `date=short` for a German text, the date's day, month, and year are separated with a space which shouldn't be the case.

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
    @misc{ebel1992,
        author  = {Martin Ebel},
        title   = {Ein Lesemarathon und der Wunsch nach mehr: Der 16. Klagenfurter (30.06.1992) Wettbewerb um den »Ingeborg-Bachmann-Preis«},
        date    = {1992-06-30},
        howpublished = {in: Badische Zeitung},
        type    = {Nr. 148},
        addendum = {S. 8},
        keywords = {presse},
    }
\end{filecontents}

%%% Bibliographie
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage[%
    style=footnote-dw,%
    date=short,%
    bibencoding=utf8,%
    backend=biber%
]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}
Foo\cite{ebel1992}
\end{document}
```

Which creates the following footnote. Note the extra date on top which I added manually in order to show how the date is supposed to look like.
[image]

Does anybody know what needs to be done in order to get rid of this extra space?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I found out how to solve this problem (thanks to this post [here](http://texwelt.de/wissen/fragen/4732/leerzeichen-im-datum-bei-biblatex-entfernen)). One has to add this into the document's preamble for the biblatex definition and overwrite the default setting:

```
%%% Fix um zwischen Tag/Monat und Monat/Jahr kein Leerzeichen zu setzen
\DefineBibliographyExtras{ngerman}{%
    \protected\def\mkbibdateshort#1#2#3{%
        \iffieldundef{#3}
        {}
        {\mkdatezeros{\thefield{#3}}\adddot
            %%% Kein Abstand zwischen Tag und Monate
            \iffieldundef{#2}{}{}}%
        \iffieldundef{#2}
        {}
        {\mkdatezeros{\thefield{#2}}%
            \iffieldundef{#1}
            {}
            %%% Kein Abstand zwischen Monat und Jahr
            {\iffieldundef{#3}{/}{\adddot}}}%
        \iffieldbibstring{#1}{\bibstring{\thefield{#1}}}
{\mkdatezeros{\thefield{#1}}}}}%
```

If anybody knows about a "cleaner" option just let me know.

Comment: You could achive this by patching (`patchcmd` et al), but that'd be quite fragile. I've opened a feature request for biblatex to implent an easier way. https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/891

Answer (score 1):

The spaces between the numbers seem to be typographically correct (see Wikipedia on [Kalenderdatum](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kalenderdatum) and [schmales Leerzeichen](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schmales_Leerzeichen)).  However, it looks very unused to me, too.  As it seems I am not allowed to comment here (yet), I'd like to mention a diff as a new answer that does the changes of your snippet but can be used if one wants to change this behaviour system-wide:

```
diff --git a/tex/latex/biblatex/lbx/german.lbx b/tex/latex/biblatex/lbx/german.lbx
--- a/tex/latex/biblatex/lbx/german.lbx
+++ b/tex/latex/biblatex/lbx/german.lbx
@@ -28,13 +28,13 @@
     \iffieldundef{#3}
       {}
       {\mkdatezeros{\thefield{#3}}\adddot
-       \iffieldundef{#2}{}{\thinspace}}%
+       \iffieldundef{#2}{}{}}%
     \iffieldundef{#2}
       {}
       {\mkdatezeros{\thefield{#2}}%
        \iffieldundef{#1}
         {}
-        {\iffieldundef{#3}{/}{\adddot\thinspace}}}%
+        {\iffieldundef{#3}{/}{\adddot}}}%
     \iffieldbibstring{#1}{\bibstring{\thefield{#1}}}{\mkdatezeros{\thefield{#1}}}}%
   \savecommand\lbx@lfromlang
   \savecommand\lbx@sfromlang
```

Edit (meaning of the the diff-formated code):

It contains 13 lines of file `german.lbx` beginning at line 28 and shows that the line prefixed with `-` is replaced by the line prefixed with `+` (the `\thinspace` is removed).  It can also be used to change the file `german.lbx` programmatically by using the [patch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Patch_%28Unix%29) utility e. g. on Linux.

Comment: And how has soneone to use this code?  Please see that not all readers know command diff.  So please explain what your given code does.  Then it is easier to understand your answer.